# Convert characters that correspond to time difference to numeric values in minutes

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector of characters that correspond calculated time like:

`calc<-c("1:17","0:46","11:25")` and I want to convert it to numeric values of minutes like `calc<-c(77,46,685)` . Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `ms` (minutes:seconds) from `lubridate` to convert to `period` class and then convert the `period` to seconds with `period_to_seconds`

```
lubridate)
period_to_seconds(ms(calc))
#[1]  77  46 685
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following base R option using `str2lang` + `gsub`

```
> eval(str2lang(sprintf("c(%s)", toString(gsub(":", "*60+", calc)))))
[1]  77  46 685
```